# Docker: Import table.sql to mydatabase

Tags: mysql, docker, import, containers

I want to import a table.sql to a created database **inside mysql container**.

This is the **Dockerfile** looks like

```
 FROM eccube/mysql51
 Maintainer Marouane baini <username@email.com>
 LABEL version="1.0"
 LABEL description="DB FOR TOMCAT SERVER"
 RUN mkdir /root/mysql
 COPY mytable.sql /root/mysql/
```

To run the container:

```
docker run --name=mysql-host  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql-host
```

Then:

```
docker exec -i mysql-host mysql -uroot -proot mydatabase < table.sql
```

I got this result :

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'mydatabase.table' doesn't exist
```

How I can resolve this, is by creating an empty table named **table** inside t **mydatabase** ?

Comment: What are the contents of `table.sql`?

Comment: It's an insert query  "insert into table (Id, Type, module, stringValue) values (...)"

Comment: Then yeah, the table should exist. You can just add a `create table` command at the top of the script

Comment: How can i do that?, because I can't create an empty table it' should be at least one column.

Comment: Ok i will add  a crate table query in the top of the script , thank you very much

Comment: I'm adding this as an answer, please accept it to allow other people with the same question to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since data can't be inserted into a non-existing table, your script should start with a `CREATE TABLE` command.